# Unable to play multiplayer on LAN

Tags: blur

I have installed Blur onto my laptop. I have friends which are on the same network connected through router, but after creating the host I am not able to see my friends on the LAN. It is not detecting the others. I have disabled Windows firewall, too, but it didn't work. Please help me to setup the LAN on Blur.

I also want to mention that I am not saying to play online with my friends. They are all on the same room and are connected to the same network.

Comment: We have closed questions like these in the past for being off topic, But in my experience, Making sure that your friends can ping your ip address as well as running nmap on the ip to make sure it is open and available. Be sure to google around first.

Comment: @ColeBusby We have?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie yeah There was one last week where someone was asking how to set up their network for a specifc game and it was downvoted to all hell and eventually put on hold.

Comment: @ColeBusby There's generic networking questions that just happen to have a game involved, and then there's "The game isn't working as expected" questions (such as this one) that networking gurus would have no special expertise with. The former get closed as off topic and the latter have a home here.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Just was saying I felt this was a How do I set up my personal network config.

Comment: @ColeBusby There aren't any close votes on this. Safe to say that, so far, the community disagrees. When you've got enough rep to close-vote, you'll have developed a better feel for where the line is, I should expect.